# Web Application Vulnerability Scanner suggestions?

Tags: security, web, web-applications, vulnerabilities

I'm looking for a new tool for the ol' admin toolkit and would value some suggestions.

I would like to do some "automated" testing of handful of websites for XSS (cross site scripting) vulns, along with checking for SQL injection opportunities. I realize that an automated tool approach isn't necessarily the only or best solution, but I'm hoping it would give me a nice start.

The sites I need to scan cover the range in stacks from PHP / MySQL to Coldfusion, with some classic ASP and ASP.NET mixed in for good measure.

What tools would you use to scan for Web application vulns?

(Please note I'm focusing on the web apps directly, not the servers themselves).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had good results from [wapiti](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/) - it scans your web forms and attempts injections and XSS attacks against them.

If you have the time, I'd suggest getting the [backtrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) distribution - it's a modified ubuntu liveCD that's been loaded up with nikto, wapiti, openVAS (a fork of nessus) and hundreds of other great security audit tools; I've used it in a few audits and had good results- it's definitely worth exploring the tools on it,.

See the nikto [step by step guide here](http://dasunhegoda.com/nikto-web-vulnerability-scanner-tutorial-imawhitehat/893/).

Comment: I think wapiti is where I'll start. Thank you for that and the backtrack tip.

Comment: I didn't think I should accept an answer on a community wiki question, however SF was urging me to so... grats! :-)

Comment: heh, too funny.

Definitely give the backtrack liveCD a shot if you get a rainy afternoon, too- includes most of the tools below and a bunch of other ones.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Nikto](http://cirt.net/nikto2)

Answer (score 3):

Start at,
The [**top 10 list from Insecure.org**](http://sectools.org/web-scanners.html) -- who give us the wonderful [**Nmap**](http://nmap.org/)

---

Some other things that appear to be missed in that list,

- [**Webshag - Web Server Audit Tool**](http://www.securiteam.com/tools/5QP0L0UQAI.html)

  > webshag is a free, multi-threaded, multi-platform web server audit tool. Written in Python, it gathers commonly useful functionalities for web server auditing like website crawling, URL scanning and file fuzzing.
- IEEE: [**Testing and Comparing Web Vulnerability Scanning Tools for SQL Injection and XSS Attacks**](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4459684&isnumber=4459625), 17-19 Dec. 2007
  But, you will need IEEE access to for that.
- WebOptimization.com: [**Server Vulnerability Scanning Service**](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/security/)
  **Not free**! But there is a 14 day free trial.

Comment: great list. I'm familiar with the "big list" at insecure.org, hadn't even noticed they had categorized versions. Very helpful!

Webshag is intriguing too. Might give that a go after I suss out wapiti.

Answer (score 2):

**[Paros Proxy](http://www.parosproxy.org/index.shtml)** is a proxy that can do spidering and automated scans.

This is a short manual to test it:

- Lauch paros.jar
- Configure your browser proxy for localhost:8080
- Navigate through the pages you want to analyze
- Complete the list with the option 'Analyze -> Spider...'
- Do an automatic scan 'Analyze -> Scan All'
- Generate a report 'Report -> Last Scan Report'

I also like **[w3af](http://w3af.sourceforge.net/)** which is a more advanced tool for web app analysis, in a similar fashion of metasploit but for web apps.

Answer (score 1):

some tools I've used, and had pretty good luck with are:

- Burp Proxy
- HP WebInspect (costs money)
- Google RatProxy (requires you to browse to the site, but it works OK and it's free)
- Fortify (not a scanner but very good at finding stuff)
- Vericode

I've also seen decent results from Cenzic Hailstrom.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or something similar to write some functional tests that exercised the web app. Then set up [ratproxy](http://code.google.com/p/ratproxy/) and rerun the tests. Ratproxy will find XSS, XSRF, and a bunch of other types of vulnerabilities.

You could also use ratproxy without the automated tests to do some manual tests. The automated tests just make it easier to rerun after you think you have fixed the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am using free online XSS scanner tool:
[link text](http://xss-scanner.com)